# VBA FormulaR1C1 property across new sheet and multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm afraid I can't wrap my head around the FormulaR1C1 property when trying to find multiple columns in another sheet, I have these formulas currently (very slowly) autofilling:

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F2:F" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R2,LU!C[1]:C[5]),"""")"
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,2,true),"""")"

Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,3,true),"""")"

Range("H2:H" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,4,true),"""")"

Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,5,true),"""")"

Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=COUNTIF(A:A,'Pivot Counter'!A7)"
```

You can see in the top formula, I've attempted it to no success. I keep getting an application defined error, but don't know enough about the property to fix it.

Comment: in the first formula where you have `R2` do you mean the actual cell `R2`? If so write this: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[12],LU!C[1]:C[5]),"""")` as R is 12 columns away from F. And in `R1C1` format, all cell references need to be in that notation. `R1C1` notation is `R[number of rows away from starting cell]C[number of columns away from starting cell]` and the numbers can be positive or negative depending on position.

Comment: No, (as I said I have no idea what I'm doing with this) I thought that's what VBA might assume as well. I really want to convert the formula underneath to the R1C1 method, first one being `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,2,true),"""")"` but not forgetting `"=COUNTIF(A:A,'Pivot Counter'!A7)"`

Comment: posting an answer now :)

Comment: One way to get the formula is to write it in a cell, then go to Options --> Formulas, choose R1C1 style.  Then look back at your formula, it'll have updated to be R1C1 style. Just take that and use it, or you can at lease see how multiple columns are handled.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, that's immensely useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula

`Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula ="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LU!A:E,2,true),"""")"`

converted to `R1C1` reference style is

```
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],LU!C[-5]:C[-1],2,True),"""")"
```

To understand it completely considering the following:

1. the cell location where you enter the formula is the starting point
2. starting column is F
3. column A is 5 columns to the left of F, so `A2` converts to `RC[-5]` (same row, 5 columns to the left of starting point (or think of 6th column (F) and move -5 from there))
4. same principle for the range lookup. You want to look in columns A:E in sheet LU. So `-5` columns from column F *(remember starting point is column F, even though it's now looking at a different sheet)* to `-1` column

Knowing this, you can convert the other formulas, even the `COUNTIF`.

Also, if you get stuck again, following @BruceWayne's suggestion of turning `R1C1` reference style under **Excel > Options > Formulas** to see what the formula would be when you type in manually.

Comment: You can also record a macro of yourself typing in the formula. The macro recorder outputs R1C1 notation.